# Cognito .Net C# Forced Password Reset enters a vicious cycle

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I am trying to integrate AWS Cognito into a web site.  I am trying to force a user to change their own password.  I already had a method for voluntary password resets and I tried to use it for forced password reset.  Here is the method:

```
internal async Task<bool> ResetPassword(string username, string oldPassword, string newPassword) {
    AmazonCognitoIdentityProviderClient provider = new AmazonCognitoIdentityProviderClient(new Amazon.Runtime.AnonymousAWSCredentials());
    CognitoUserPool userPool = new CognitoUserPool(CognitoHelper.POOL_ID, CognitoHelper.CLIENTAPP_ID, provider);
    CognitoUser user = new CognitoUser(username, CognitoHelper.CLIENTAPP_ID, userPool, provider);
    InitiateSrpAuthRequest authRequest = new InitiateSrpAuthRequest() {
        Password = oldPassword
    };

    AuthFlowResponse authResponse = await user.StartWithSrpAuthAsync(authRequest).ConfigureAwait(false);
    await user.ChangePasswordAsync(oldPassword, newPassword);

    return true;
} // ResetPassword
```

When I call this method on a voluntary password reset, it works fine.  On a forced password reset, the "StartWithSrpAuthAsync" throws an exception complaining "Password reset required for the user".  No kidding - that is why I am trying to change the password.

The problem is that the "ChangePasswordAsync" method requires the user be authenticated before it is called.  I can't authenticate the user because the password needs to be reset, but I can't change the password because the user needs to be authenticated first.

I tried a hack to solve my issue by catching the "Password reset required for the user" exception hoping the user was authenticated anyway.  Unfortunately no luck:

```
internal async Task<bool> ResetPassword(string username, string oldPassword, string newPassword) {
    AmazonCognitoIdentityProviderClient provider = new AmazonCognitoIdentityProviderClient(new Amazon.Runtime.AnonymousAWSCredentials());
    CognitoUserPool userPool = new CognitoUserPool(CognitoHelper.POOL_ID, CognitoHelper.CLIENTAPP_ID, provider);
    CognitoUser user = new CognitoUser(username, CognitoHelper.CLIENTAPP_ID, userPool, provider);
    InitiateSrpAuthRequest authRequest = new InitiateSrpAuthRequest() {
        Password = oldPassword
    };

    try {
        AuthFlowResponse authResponse = await user.StartWithSrpAuthAsync(authRequest).ConfigureAwait(false);
        await user.ChangePasswordAsync(oldPassword, newPassword);
    } catch (Exception exp) {
        if (exp.Message == "Password reset required for the user") {
            await user.ChangePasswordAsync(oldPassword, newPassword);
        } else {
            throw exp;
        } // if else
    } // try catch
    return true;
} // ResetPassword
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried treating a forced reset like a forgot password case and it worked!  Specifically to send a new verification code to the user's email:

```
    internal async Task<ForgotPasswordResponse> ForgotPassword(string username) {
        ForgotPasswordRequest forgotPasswordRequest = new ForgotPasswordRequest();
        forgotPasswordRequest.Username = username;
        forgotPasswordRequest.ClientId = CLIENTAPP_ID;

        ForgotPasswordResponse forgotPasswordResponse = await provider.ForgotPasswordAsync(forgotPasswordRequest).ConfigureAwait(false);
        return forgotPasswordResponse;
    } // ForgotPassword
```

and:

```
    internal async Task<ConfirmForgotPasswordResponse> ConfirmForgotPassword(string validationCode, string username, string newPassword) {
        ConfirmForgotPasswordRequest confirmForgotPasswordRequest = new ConfirmForgotPasswordRequest();
        confirmForgotPasswordRequest.Username = username;
        confirmForgotPasswordRequest.ClientId = CLIENTAPP_ID;
        confirmForgotPasswordRequest.Password = newPassword;
        confirmForgotPasswordRequest.ConfirmationCode = validationCode;

        ConfirmForgotPasswordResponse confirmForgotPasswordResponse = await provider.ConfirmForgotPasswordAsync(confirmForgotPasswordRequest).ConfigureAwait(false);
        return confirmForgotPasswordResponse;
    } // ConfirmForgotPassword
```

to "reset" the new password.  From what I can see in the documentation, this is not spelled out anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code (in the first question) and got the same error
Changing the provider declaration as follows fixed it

```
static Amazon.RegionEndpoint region = Amazon.RegionEndpoint.APSoutheast2;


AmazonCognitoIdentityProviderClient provider = new AmazonCognitoIdentityProviderClient(new Amazon.Runtime.AnonymousAWSCredentials(), region);
```

Of course the region should be changed to whatever region you are on